# how to use xilinx macros in activeHDL?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I have xilinx macros for uart (.edn files) and i don't know how to use the in activehdl
when i simulate the macros the give uninitialized output ? so what if any one can help me with the right way to use the macro ...?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Xilinx uniMacro library. You may need to compile or download it for your simulator.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveHDL is a simulator package. It typically operates by compile VHDL or Verilog code. The "macros" you are refering to with the extension ".edn" are EDIF netlist files. These are not files that can typically be used by simulator, but are in almost all cases only usable by the synthesizer for the exact device they are targeting.

It may be the case that ActelHDL can import EDIF files. In this case, it still will only work if the primitives used by the EDIF file are also added as part of the project. As another answer said, this most likely would be primitives from the Xilinx unisim library.

The best option is to probably run the EDIF files you have through the Xilinx tools (specifically "Translate" (ngdbuild) and "Generate Simulation Netlist" (netgen)) to generate a simulation model for these pieces. The result will likely require the Xilinx unisim and simprims libraries, which are usually available precompiled for most simulators, but can also easily just be pointed to the source in the Xilinx ISE install.